# can't connect to google cloud sql with phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have a second generation Google Cloud SQL instance running and can connect to it by IP address and through a proxy that Google provides, only when I use a cli. When I try to connect with phpMyAdmin or Adminer, I get an error like "Can't connect to MySql on ...". The server that I'm trying to connect from runs centos7. Anyone come across this before?

Comment: Have you taken a look at https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/phpmyadmin-on-app-engine?

Comment: @sundaresanvenkatasubramanian thanks but i'm using compute engine

Answer (score 0):

I ran the below line on the compute engine instance I was connecting from. 
Not sure what this is but it made everything work.

```
sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db on
```

Apparently this was/is [an issue](https://code.google.com/p/googlecloudsql/issues/detail?id=81).